# Django Update Class form (delete form imput title)

Tags: django, jinja2

I have:

```
class CompanyUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
model = UserCompany

template_name = 'panel/admin/company.html'

fields = [
    "name",
    "phone_number",
    "address",
    "city",
    "region",
    "legal_document",
]

success_url ="/panel"
```

and HTML:

```
<div class="col-6">
        {{ form.name|as_crispy_field }}
</div>
```

and return:

[image]

How i change the label

Comment: i can't understand what you want to change! the label? or the value of the input?

Comment: yes the label .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this

```
<div class="col-6">
    <label for='id_name'>what name you want</label>
    {{ form.name|as_crispy_field }}
</div>
```

actually you can overwrite the default label with adding a new label tag up of your fields, but only when you put your fields apart, but when you put your form directly, like {{ form|crispy }}, you need to add the label in your forms.py like this:

```
class YourForm(forms.ModelForm):

    title = forms.CharField(label='what ever you want')
    ...
```